# Drive Icon replaced by a 2002 cat simulation game

Tags: windows-explorer

So not that it's a big issue [hopefully] but I'm curious as to what may have caused this and what I would do to restore it. Basically my D:/ drive icon has just been replaced for some reason[image: haunted drive picture]

Comment: Sometimes icons need to be rebuild. Try full restart, not Sleep, Hibernate, without Windows fast startup, to see if it fixes the issue, and let us know if that does it.

Comment: Is there a file called `autorun.inf` located in the root of D:\?

Comment: @MMM yeah there is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon is most likely set by a file called `autorun.inf` located in the root of your `D:\` drive. This file is normally used by CD-ROMs to add an icon to the disk as well as define autorun actions, such as launching a setup file or a menu. Starting with Windows 7, Microsoft removed the ability to automatically run programs using this file, but left in the ability to set the drive's icon.

Deleting the file or moving it to a different location other than `D:\` should return the icon back to normal. You probably at some point copied the data from your cat game over to your harddrive, and might've copied it directly to your root directory.